# Silently install app in teams in channel and group chat

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using Adaptive Card with JustInTimeInstall action to install the bot with message extension based on consent from user. How to silently install like first-party apps like "Microsoft Forms"?

How this will be supported in mobile devices? currently, it won't respond to the install action and I'm showing a message to install the app from desktop/web.

Comment: @mdrichardson-msft any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please look at [install app for user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging#install-the-app-for-your-users)

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT thanks for the pointer, will give a try. Interested to see how it plays group chat conversation.